# Not-so-nonsensical Cocktail Globulus—What are we?

Tags: riddle, word

*Each bullet point yields a distinct word.*

- > My animal torments you in sleep.
  >   Big or small, she is feared by all.
  >   You may choose to laugh her off,
  >   but she's not so easy to forget.
  >   I preside her alright, however
  >   she is not entirely bound to me.
  >   She might too come
  >   when my opposite occupies.
- > A black blob in lunar froth I am.
  >   Be my fruit, and cherished you will be.
  >   I shout, when you are sad.
  >   You keep me out, when you're on guard.
  >   Bat me, when capturing hearts is your intention.
- > Back is at my start;
  >   red marble rolls after.
  >   Overcome me,
  >   or else you are stuck forever...

What are we?

Comment: Okay... Where is the crossword? Cryptic-crossword tag applies to solving crosswords containing cryptic clues. I don't see any crossword here. If you want to draw attention to your puzzle, you could put up a bounty or give some more hints.

Comment: I am not sure why, but I can see you have been modifying the part of the riddle which is already solved and not the one which is unsolved since long now. Either modify the unsolvable part or add a hint. If you want your riddle to get some good views, you can always add a bounty.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Gandalf for the first piece. Haven't got the third but the second seems to be:

> Eye

A black blob in lunar froth I am.

> Reference to a pupil (black blob) surrounded by the white of the eye (lunar froth)

Be my fruit, and cherished you will be.

> As in "apple of my eye"

I shout, when you are sad.

> Crying

You keep me out, when you're on guard.

> As in "keep an eye out"

Bat me, when capturing hearts is your intention.

> Batting your eyes (or eyelashes) at a lover.

Comment: Yeah, you got it! I originally meant "keep an eye out" by the way.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine, if that's the case, a better line might have been "You keep me out, when you're on guard." But I love like imagery of "a black blob in lunar froth"!

Comment: @Silenus Took your suggestion. Edited the OP.

Answer (score 4):

My animal torments you in sleep.
Big or small, she is feared by all.
You may choose to laugh her off,
but she's not easy to forget.

> You are **night**. Your animal is *nightmare*.

I preside her alright, however
she is not entirely bound to me.
She might too come
when my opposite occupies.

> `Night` comes before `mare` in `nightmare`. But that doesn't mean nightmares are  limited to only night. They can also come during the day (night's opposite).

Comment: As it's Valentine's day, maybe something to do with a avtugzner qngr?  But that doesn't explain the final piece.

Comment: Night is the answer. Night is talking about her mare - which is nightmare. So, the 'me' is 'night'.

Answer (score 2):

The last one:

is it:

> Backgammon?

Back is at my start;
red marble rolls after.
Overcome me,
or else you are stuck forever...

> Back is at the start-True. Red dice is used while playing. I don't know the exact rules but it's like removing the opponents' checkers or something like that. You are stuck forever- could refer to continuously playing without winning.

Comment: Nice Guess! It could easily fit, but still that's not the word I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The remaining piece of the puzzle...  Could it be

> a video camera/player, remote control, cassette player or similar?

Back is at my start;

> a back, reverse, or "play back" button (often) comes first if you interpret left to right as first to last

red marble rolls after.

> perhaps the record button?  Usually a large round red dot.

Overcome me,
 or else you are stuck forever...

> a reference to the stop or pause button?